# How to change orientation in Gridview (Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

In `gridview` my data showing in **horizontal direction** how to change that in **vertical direction** 
Because I'm using ItemTemplate and `TemplateField` in `gridview` and I want to see the data one by one i.e in `Row`

Comment: I want like this link-http://goo.gl/dFnjVa

Comment: Try Repeater if your grid is simple.

Comment: you can use repeater control

Comment: I know I can use Repeater or DataList control but I want to do this with gridview control

Answer (score 0):

please follow below link It might help u to solve your problem
May be this is what you're looking for:
http://forums.asp.net/post/2305635.aspx

You can also follow below link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/214138/change-orientation-of-a-grid-view.aspx